Same Mayonnaise, etc. for both meat and dairy
May one dip cold dairy and meat knives (for spreading) into the same mayonnaise jar? If not, would it be more lenient if it was a fork or spoon? What about jellies?

Please add reasons why you think that any of this would be an issue

Are the knives/forks clean?
